# Rescue From If JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, rescue

I'd like to rescue from a RecordNotFound exception if, and only if, the request is JSON. Now if I was doing this for a `skip_before_action`, I would do the below:

```
skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token, if: :json_request?
```

Is there syntax for this in `rescue_from`? Something like:

```
rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, :with => :record_not_found, if: :json_request?
```

Helper method:

```
protected
  def json_request?
    request.format.json?
  end
```

Comment: You could rescue it either way and rethrow it if it is not a json request?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am assuming if the request is not `JSON` then you want to raise? If so you should be able to do this

```
rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound { request.format.json? ? record_not_found : super }
```

OR

```
rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, with: lambda{|e| request.format.json? ? record_not_found(e) : raise(e) }
```

These will have identical impact because if a block is given it assigns it to the `options[:with]` where as if `with:` is supplied it uses this as the block and ignores any other block passed to it

`rescue_from` takes a splat argument called `*klasses` and a `block`. It then parses `*klasses` to determine the options passed in of which it only cares about `:with`. It then applies the `:with` block to the key(s) which will represent exception class names to handle.

There is no additional options that will be acknowledged.

Please be advised I have not tested this

Comment: I attempted your bottom syntax with error: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting =>

Comment: @steventnorris sorry edited my answer forgot to writer lambda as it needs to be a callable object.

Comment: Still yields errors. On an html call: super called outside of method. On a json call: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1) [referring to the record_not_found method]

Comment: @steventnorris does `record_not_found` need an argument?

Comment: The json request forms correctly. However, the html request renders a blank html page

Comment: throw(e) works for that last bit. edit the answer and I'll accept. Thanks!

Comment: @steventnorris great I will edit the answer for others that stumble across it although since this a rescue can you try raise as it seems more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound do
  record_not_found if json_request?
end
```

I dont think there is another syntax for that exact case :-(

Comment: This does not work. It renders a blank html page on record not found.